# Using pipe JSON has wrong moment value

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm printing an object and it has the wrong value for the _moment property if a pipe is used, it has the correct value when printing object.moment so it seems the pipe is causing it the go back in time. Why is it printing the wrong moment with pipe?

I have an object with a getter and setting for the moment:

```
private _moment: Moment;
set moment(moment: Moment) {
    this._moment = moment;
    this._date = moment.toString();
}
get moment(): Moment {
    return this._moment;
}
```

When I print the object like this:

```
<div>Editing = {{currentDay | json}}</div>
<div>moment = {{currentDay.moment}}</div>
```

The pipe print shows the wrong value for the `currentDay`

This is the correct value:

```
moment = Thu Jan 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100
```

And here is the piped one printing the wrong value:

```
Editing = { "format": "MMMM Do YYYY", "onServer": true, "_moment": "2019-01-16T13:00:00.000Z", "_date": "2019-01-17T00:00:00", "income": 1, "expenses": 5 }
```

The moment is one day ago:

```
"_moment": "2019-01-16T13:00:00.000Z"
```

actual date:

```
"_date": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
```

Comment: can you use the date pipe ? this is locale dependant , by default en-us

Comment: what is the pipe for?